# How do you create a link to a .html.erb file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

Ive created a new about page in Ruby on Rails called `about.html.erb`. How do I create a link to it?

Here is another link I have, Im just not how to write another one for myself.

```
<%= link_to "Learn more", new_property_path, class: "btn btn-home"  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out documentation for [#link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). If you are not sure about second argument you can run *bundle exec rake routes* and check what url helper you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to create a route in **config/routes.rb** for this new "about" action.

An example of route would be:

```
get "about" => "<name_of_controller>#about", as: "about"
```

*PD: Remember to change the  to the actual controller's name.*

Then you will be able to use a link like this:

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "btn btn-home"  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Learn more", new_property_path, class: "btn btn-home"  %>
```

So it's quite straight forward - the first is the name, the last is the css class, you can and probably should reuse these to maintain visual consistency. The middle bit is the piece that will confuse you.

the path comes from your routes.rb file - which is in the config directory. You will need to have a path set up there to use it in the link.

You can run 'rake routes' to see the current mappings that you have. you get a format of:

```
 new_user_account GET    /user/new(.:format)                                                                                                                                                             user#new
```

They key to them is that you add path to the first item - so 'new_user_account_path' and it will point to 'user#new' which is the new method in the user controller.

To add routes, you edit the file, and while there are quite a few ways of doing things, your basic CRUD operations are covered by a line of:

```
resources :users
```

This will give you more info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html is a guide to this